# Deselect top option in <select> - bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a [bootstrap multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) html element that i fill with data from a web service call that gets a list of regions in New Zealand. I need to load those options into the `<select>` and not select the top option by default.

I have tried everything that is done via the **bootstrap multiselect built in functions and options**. Nothing will work. So i am resorting to vanilla javascript or vanilla jquery to go straight into the plain html and deselect the first option.

All work on this can be done in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/181/)

I had to copy paste a minified external resource (xml2json.min.js) into the top of the javascript editor because it wasn't playing nicely when I tried to add it as an external resource.

I have tried this:

```
$("ul.multiselect-container").find("li").removeClass("active");
```

And it doesn't work. It removes the active class but doesn't deselect the option. How do I deselect the option?

I have tried this:

```
$("ul.multiselect-container").find('input[type="radio":checked]').prop('checked', false);
```

It doesn't deselect the option.

Please see if you can deselect the top option of the select.

So the jsfiddle at url same as above but ending in 182 is my refactoring to try and make it easier for people to understand but it didn't end up working correctly on my friends laptop.

When using the plugin as a `<select multiple=true>` it doesn't select the top option by default. However I need that same behaviour with a normal `<select>`

Comment: Do you have codePen or jsFiddle for this one

Comment: @SridharGudimela http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/181/ thanks

Comment: I tried adding selected='false' in every option at line no 38 in your jsfiddle that actually unselected the first option. However it selected the last one. Will try more and will see if there i any better way to deselect everything or by using selectedIndex = -1.

Comment: The first example here seems to do what you asked for.. http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look in the plugin, And here is what I understood, `To remove default selection` you must have your selection set as **multiple='multiple'**, This is when you can see a Checkbox in the drop down rather than radio buttons.

If you do not put this multiple option set then you will end up in having a radio button and this will set the first value by default. Here is the [Fiddle which doesnt not select any default](http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/186/) value. I just added the option `multiple='multiple'` to your dynamic select tag.

To have the option multi select set and also be able to select only one at a time use the below code. You need to replace your code block with this one

```
        $("body").prepend("<select id=\"a-select\" multiple='multiple' >"             
        + optionsText +
        "</select>");

        $('#a-select').multiselect({
        on: {
            change: function(option, checked) {
                alert('sdd');
                var values = [];
                $('#a-select').each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() !== option.val()) {
                        values.push($(this).val());
                    }
                });

                $('#a-select').multiselect('deselect', values);
            }
        }
    });
```

Logic taken from http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples, see the 5th example from here which says `Simulate single selections using checkboxes`.

Comment: Thanks. I do already have some multi-selects in my website that don't default to selecting an option. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in the question. I need some single selects too, and they should not select an option by default, in order to be consistent with the multiselects. It seems weird that the plugin made their multi-selects and single selects inconsistent with eachother.

Comment: Ok, there is a way to acheive what you want, But your fiddle has lot of errors I think its breaking my logic, Anyways I will add the code here and see if you can get it working in your end.

Comment: I made the multiselect behave like a single select. Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkzb272j/199/

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins Nice

Answer (score 1):

I have redefined the method "deselect" as follows.

```
 this.deselect = function() {
      $('input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('checked', false);
     $(".multiselect-selected-text").text("None selected");
  }
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/bkzb272j/190/)

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty option to the top of the `select` element.